# A tangent property of an incircle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> In $ \triangle{ABC}$ with $ AB = 12$, $ BC = 13$, and $ AC = 15$, let $ M$ be a point on $ \overline{AC}$ such that the incircles of $ \triangle{ABM}$ and $ \triangle{BCM}$ have equal radii. Let $ p$ and $ q$ be positive relatively prime integers such that $ \tfrac{AM}{CM} = \tfrac{p}{q}$. Find $ p + q$.

It seems that a rather obvious solution in terms of insight is to find a ratio of areas, but I was reading a more synthetic solution that brought up a confusing claim.

First, let the incenters be $I_1$ and $I_2$ for $\triangle ABM$ and $\triangle CBM$ respectively, and point $P$ is the radius from $I_1$ to $AM$. It is then claimed that $MP=(MA+MB-AB)/2$.

I've tried manipulating some relations, but I'm stuck. How can we prove this?

Comment: @torontohrb This is not necessarily true, since the radii of the two incricles do not necessarily meet at the same point.

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the incircle $\Gamma$ of $\Delta ABM$ touch the sides $AB$ and $BM$ at $Q$ and $R$ respectively. It already touches $AM$ at $P$ as the problem mentions.

Then $AP=AQ=x\ (\text{say})$, since they are tangents from the point $A$ to $\Gamma$.

Similarly, we have $BQ=BR=y\ (\text{say})$ and $MP=MR=z \ (\text{say})$.

Then, if you have already marked the points as outlined,

$$x+y=AB,\ y+z=BM, \ z+x=MA \\ \implies 2(x+y+z) = AB+BM+MA \\ \implies MP = z= x+y+z-(x+y) = \dfrac{AB+BM+MA}2-AB = \dfrac{MA+MB-AB}2$$

This is a well-known formula for the distance between the vertex of a triangle and it's intouch point (point of contact of triangle with incirle) on a side. containing that vertex.

Comment: Oh, this is just an application of the dual principle.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is true for every triangle.
[Triangle with Incenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU7Bp.png)

By Congruency (RHS) it can  be proven that

From this one can prove that MP=(MA+MB−AB)/2